# erl-toolbar available on Erlang v19 compiled from tar ball?

Tags: software-installation, erlang

[Not sure this is the right place to ask... if not so, let me know and I will take my post down.]

I just installed Erlang v19 from the tar ball on a Ubuntu 14.04.5 box.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libpng3
$ wget http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_19.1.tar.gz
$ tar -zxf otp_src_19.1.tar.gz
$ cd otp_src_19.1
$ export ERL_TOP=`pwd`
$ ./configure
$ ./make
$ sudo make install
```

Installation in `/usr/local/bin/` went well (no errors and passed all dry-test runs) and I can run the erl shell and execute the basic code I am starting to write.

However I want to use the toolbar described in section 1.2.1 of "getting started" on erlang.org. The description there and elsewhere mentions debugging, trace visual, process management (Pman) as the toolbar features ...

But as I start the shell with `$ erl -s toolbar` Erlang crashes and gives me:

> Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2]
>   [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
>       {"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{toolbar,start,[],[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
>       init terminating in do_boot ()
>       Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Can someone help me with that ? Is the toolbar available for v19 ? Did I forget compilation options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use observer:start() which is the replacement for the old gui
tools, or debugger:start() if it is the debugger you are looking for.

http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2016-November/090858.html